# If statement being ignored

Tags: javascript

My `if` statement is being ignored. I'm pretty new to coding.
I feel like I am missing a semicolon or a parenthesis or something small like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showdiv() {     
       if(document.getElementById("nav-wrap-2").style.opacity ='.5')
            {
            document.getElementById("nav-wrap-2").style.opacity ='0';
            document.getElementById("content-wrap").style.marginLeft ='250px';
            }
       }
</script>
```

Edit: Changing = to == in the if statement was the correct solution, however it did not solve the whole problem. I also had to get rid of the quotes around the '.5' in the if statement.
Derp.

Comment: I recommend to use tools such as http://www.jshint.com/ to support your development process. It would have made you aware of the problem.

Comment: It IS working, it is just that the assignment in the conditional returns the assigned value ".5" so for instance this alerts .5 alert(weather=".5"); and all non-empty strings are a "truthy" value in Javascript - so the opacity is set to .5 then to 0 in the first statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use "==" to compare. (Or "===" to compare by value *and* type)

"=" will perform assignment in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`if(document.getElementById("nav-wrap-2").style.opacity ='.5')` uses an assignment, you should use

```
if(document.getElementById("nav-wrap-2").style.opacity == '.5')
```

which will use the equals operator `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an assigment not a comparison. You have to use the == operator instead of =.

= is an assigment.

== checks if to values are equal.

Your code should look like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("nav-wrap-2").style.opacity =='.5')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the = to ==. In JavaScript if you do =, it's an assignment operator, not a comparer.