# knockout js: ko.utils.arrayFilter is not working properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So i recently inserted what i want to be a filtering system into a project of mine using knockout.js. I inserted the following code into my project.

```
self.pointsFilter = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pointsList(), function(pointItem){
      return pointItem.done = true;
    })
  });
```

and here is my exisiting code previously:

```
var point = function(obj){
  var self = this;

  this.name = obj.name;
  this.street = obj.street;
  this.city = obj.city;
  this.state = obj.stat;
  this.zip = obj.zip;
  this.food = ko.observable(obj.food);
  this.lat = ko.observable(obj.lat);
  this.lng = ko.observable(obj.lng);
  this.map = map;

  this.fullAddress = function(){
    return self.street + self.city + "</br>" + self.state + self.zip;
  };

  this.formattedAddress = function(){
    var currentStreet = self.street + self.city + self.state + self.zip;
    var newAddress = currentStreet.replace(/ /g, '+');
    return newAddress;
  };

  this.formattedName = function(){
    var newName = self.name.replace(/ /g, '');
    return newName;
  }

}
```

and

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  var marker;

  this.pointsList = ko.observableArray([]);

  points.forEach(function(pointItem){
    self.pointsList.push(new point(pointItem));
  });

  self.pointsList().forEach(function(pointItem){

    console.log(pointItem.formattedName());
    console.log(pointItem.formattedAddress());

    pointItem.marker = marker;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(pointItem.lat(), pointItem.lng()),
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      if(infowindow.marker != marker){
        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'),
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        infowindow.setContent('<div><h1>' + pointItem.name +
        '</h1><h2>' + pointItem.fullAddress() +
        '</h2><img src=' + streetViewRequest +
        '><div id="instafeed">' + '</div</div>' + instafeedRequest());
      }
    });

  });    

  self.pointsFilter = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pointsList(), function(pointItem){
      return pointItem.done = true;
    })
  })

}
```

if you would like the fill github repository, you can find it here
[current github repository](https://github.com/omar-jandali/udacity-map)

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647114/if-statement-being-ignored

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Boolean` result in your `return` statement of the filter to only return things that have a done value of true. Your single equals was doing an assignment not a `Boolean` comparison.

In other words, you need a double (or triple equals for non-coerced values), like this:

```
return pointItem.done == true;
```

Comment: so i have the js for a filter and I have the filter box but it does not do anything. So i want to get the name that they input to enable the infowindow for that location to open. would I have to add a new event lister or somehow trigger an info window that already exists...